# Infinispan configuration

Tags: infinispan

I am bit confused reading Infinispan guide.

I want to have two clustered caches, propably must have separate jgroups files to have different multicast addresses, but should there be only one cache containter?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:8.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-8.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:8.0">

    <jgroups>
        <stack-file name="file1" path="jgroups1.xml" /> 
        <stack-file name="file2" path="jgroups2.xml" />

    </jgroups>

<cache-container default-cache="cache1">  
    <transport stack="file1" node-name="${nodeName}" /> 

    <invalidation-cache name="cache1" configuration="invalidation-template" />
    <invalidation-cache name="cache2" configuration="invalidation-template" />

    <invalidation-cache-configuration name="invalidation-template" mode="SYNC" >
        <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED" striping="true"/>
        <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC"/>
        <eviction max-entries="20500" strategy="LRU"/>
        <expiration interval="10500" />
    </invalidation-cache-configuration>

     </cache-container>

 </infinispan>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have a separate jgroups file for each clustered cache. Simply configure the transport element of the cache-container, and then you can define any number of caches in that cache-container.

Answer (score 1):

Different multicast addresses are only needed if you want cache containers to form different clusters. I think the confusing thing here is that you can define multiple `stack-file` elements in JGroups but you can only really specify a single `cache-container` element. The XSD is not precise enough, but the parser within the code assumes a single global configuration builder instance, hence a single cache container. So, if you want to create two separate cache containers, these should be currently defined in separate XML files.

Comment: I've created [ISPN-6344](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-6344) to address the confusion.